# Excel Interop - Find Sum of a Column Values

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have following way of invoking and using Excel utilizing Excel Interop:

```
Dim ExcelTestSetOutput, Sheet1TestSetOutput
ExcelTestSetOutput = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”) ' Open Excel
ExcelTestSetOutput.WorkBooks.Add() ' Add a new workbook

'Get the first worksheet.
 Sheet1TestSetOutput = ExcelTestSetOutput.ActiveSheet

Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput, 1).Value = "ID"                  ' A
Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput, 2).Value = "Parent Path"                     ' B 
Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput, 3).Value = "Name"                   ' C
Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput, 4).Value = "Last Modified"             ' D
Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput, 5).Value = "Script Size"                   ' E

Dim n
For n = 1 To RecSetTestSet.RecordCount
  Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput + 1, 1).Value = RecSetTestSet.FieldValue(0)
  Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput + 1, 2).Value = RecSetTestSet.FieldValue(1)
  Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput + 1, 3).Value = RecSetTestSet.FieldValue(2)
  Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput + 1, 4).Value = RecSetTestSet.FieldValue(3)
  Sheet1TestSetOutput.Cells(RowTestSetOutput + 1, 5).Value = RecSetTestSet.FieldValue(4)


  RowTestSetOutput = RowTestSetOutput + 1
  RecSetTestSet.Next()

Next

Dim eTotal As Long

' eTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(columns((rReportData.column))
' eTotal = SUM(Sheet1TestSetOutput.Range("E2:E"))
' eTotal = ExcelTestSetOutput.ActiveSheet.Sum("E2:E")
' eTotal = Sheet1TestSetOutput.Range("E:E").FormulaR1C1("sum(R2E1:R100E1)")
```

All are working, except I cannot get a value for eTotal.

eTotal needs to sum all values from column E. Column E's last row number can vary.

I have commented out 4 lines of code where I tried to sum column E to get value into eTotal variable, but error message states that the function is not supported under Worksheeet. Hoping to get your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eTotal = ExcelTestSetOutput.Evaluate("=SUM(E:E)")
```